# Find new left and top corresponding to original left and top on CSS rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose my div has left:200px and top:400px, after I apply a rotate transform of suppose 90 deg the above top and left positions no more point to the old positions. Now how can we calculate the new top and left for the transformed div which are equivalent to the left and top positions of the non-transformed div after rotation.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited answer**

Besides the starting position of the corner point (top-left in your example), and the rotation angle, we also need to know the position of the reference point of the rotation. This is the point around which we rotate the `div` (CSS calls it `transform-origin`). If you don't specify it, then normally, the centre of mass of the element is used.

I don't know of any JavaScript method that simply calculates it for you, but I can show you its Math, and a simple JS implementation.

**Math**

P: original position of the corner point, with (Px, Py) coordinates
O: reference point of the rotation, with (Ox, Oy) coordinates

1. Calculate the original position of P, relative to O.
   `x = Px - Ox`
   `y = Py - Oy`
2. Calculate the rotated position of P, relative to O.
   `x' = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)`
   `y' = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle)`
3. Convert this position back to the original coordinate system.
   `Px' = x' + Ox`
   `Py' = y' + Oy`

*If you're not aware of the formulas in step #2, you can find an explanation [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/286454-simple-2d-point-rotation/#entry2800395).*

**JavaScript implementation**

```
function rotatedPosition(pLeft, pTop, oLeft, oTop, angle){
    // 1
    var x = pLeft - oLeft;
    var y = pTop - oTop;

    // 2
    var xRot = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle);
    var yRot = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);

    // 3
    var pLeftRot = xRot + oLeft;
    var pTopRot = yRot + oTop

    return {left: pLeftRot, top: pTopRot};
}
```

`rotatedPosition` requires you to define the original position of the point and the reference point, plus the angle.
In case you need a method which takes only a single argument, the div element itself, and computes the rest for you, then you can do something like:

```
function divTopLeftRotatedPosition(div){
    var pLeft = // ...
    var pTop = // ...

    var width = // ...
    var height = // ...

    var angle = // ...

    return rotatedPosition(pLeft, pTop, pLeft + width / 2, pTop + height / 2, angle);
}
```

Comment: the `left` and `top` got from this approach are not the `left` and `top` ***of the specific corner*** (such as the corner `left-top`). For the `left-corner`, before rotating `30deg`, it has value of `X`, but after rotating `30deg`, its value should be some value ***greater than*** `X`, but the `left` got here is less than `X`.

Comment: you may misunderstood the OP's question, the value `90deg` is just a ***supposition***. For e.g, a `div` of 4 points A, B, C, D. At first `A` is the left-top corner, after rotating, he still wants to know the `left-top` values of `A` not of any other corners.

Comment: You may be right. He asked for the new `top` and `left` for the **transformed div**, though, which rather refers to the entire element, not a specific corner of it. Using the term `left-top`, as you wrote it, would've been more obvious. I'm editing my answer.. thank you for the comment.